# Update From Select with Correlated Subquery and Join in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, correlated-subquery

I am migrating from SQL Server to Postgres and it has gone okay for the most part. One of the issues is that I am unable to figure out how to make this query work in Postgres:

```
update
    "Measure"
set 
    DefaultStrataId = StrataId

FROM (SELECT "Strata"."MeasureId",
               Min("Strata"."index") AS "Index"
        FROM   "Strata",
               "Measure"
        WHERE  "Strata"."MeasureId" = "Measure"."MeasureId" and "Strata"."StrataId" in (select strataid from point)
        GROUP  BY "Strata"."MeasureId") a
       INNER JOIN strata 
               ON "Strata"."index" = a."index"
               where "Strata"."MeasureId" = "Measure"."MeasureId";
```

It complains: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"`

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Start by rewiting your query to a sane syntactic form, and the answer will come naturally. Start by using aliases and join-syntax. The mixedCaseIdentifiers and the required quotes dont help readability either. #rant

Comment: SQL Server made me do it. The join syntax point and aliases are true, I just got lazy. I'm not sure how why you said that the answer would come naturally though. It's seems to be something that postgres doesn't like in the actual syntax.

Comment: If you have any say in the database design, I'd get rid of all of those double-quoted field names and go with the case-independent versions (`measure_id` or `measureid` instead of `"MeasureId"`).  It will save you so much heartache in the long run.  I know SQL Server seems to encourage the multi-casing, but personally it gives me vertigo to look at.  If you make it non-specific, you can reference it any way you want in the query -- for example `select MeasureId` will work, as will `select MEASUREID` or `select measureid`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DISTINCT ON for this to simplify it.
The ORDER BY in the sub-query will make sure that it's the "StrataId" for the minimum "index".

```
UPDATE "Measure" m
SET "DefaultStrataId" = q."StrataId"
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (s."MeasureId") s."MeasureId", s."index", s."StrataId"
  FROM "Strata" s
  JOIN "Point" p ON p."StrataId" = s."StrataId"
  JOIN "Measure" m ON m."MeasureId" = s."MeasureId"
  ORDER BY s."MeasureId", s."index"
) q
WHERE q."MeasureId" = m."MeasureId";
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=36111a123530d2c027e990a72d75aafc)*

Btw, the query below also works with the test data in that fiddle.
Basically, in Postgresql quoting a name isn't the same as not quoting a name.
MS Sql Server is much more tolerant in that aspect.

```
UPDATE "Measure"
SET "DefaultStrataId" = "StrataId"
FROM (SELECT "Strata"."MeasureId",
               Min("Strata"."index") AS "index"
        FROM   "Strata",
               "Measure"
        WHERE  "Strata"."MeasureId" = "Measure"."MeasureId" and "Strata"."StrataId" in (select "StrataId" from "Point")
        GROUP  BY "Strata"."MeasureId") a
       INNER JOIN "Strata" 
               ON "Strata"."index" = a."index"
               where "Strata"."MeasureId" = "Measure"."MeasureId";
```

Answer (score 0):

Funky. After feeling shamed by @wildplasser to make my query non-disgusting, everything magically started working. It's not like I changed anything except switching to standard joins and adding aliases:

```
update
    "Measure" m set
        "DefaultStrataId" = "StrataId"
    from
        (
        select
            s."MeasureId",
            min(s."Index") as "Index"
        from
            "Measure" m
        inner join "Strata" s on
            s."MeasureId" = m."MeasureId"
        where s."StrataId" in (
            select
                s."StrataId"
            from
                "Point")
        group by
            s."MeasureId") a
    inner join "Strata" s on
        s."Index" = a."Index"
    where
        s."MeasureId" = m."MeasureId";
```

Comment: Your query references `Measure` twice, `Strata` twice, and `Point` once. Give them *different* aliases; this is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Your only goal appears to be getting the minimal value from Strata

Omitting all the ugly quotes,and adding some aliasses (assuming that only one record with the minumum value exists) :

---

```
UPDATE Measure m
SET    DefaultStrataId = s.StrataId
FROM   Strata s
WHERE  s.MeasureId = m.MeasureId
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Strata nx
        where nx.MeasureId = s.MeasureId  
        AND nx."index" < s."index"  
        )
        ;
```